# Cannot load canvas app inside lightning component on community page

Tags: lightning, canvas, aura, community-builder

I built a custom Lightning component that shows up in the community builder, but when I drag it on to the page and preview it, I only see a loading bar.

In the js console, I am seeing that CanvasRendering.js is throwing a 404 when it tries to load [instance.force.com/s/canvas/proxy.js](http://instance.force.com/s/canvas/proxy.js), but I did find that proxy.js exists at [instance.force.com/canvas/proxy.js](http://instance.force.com/canvas/proxy.js). I'm assuming this is why my component is not loading, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm on Winter '17 release. Here is my aura component code (it works as expected with an iframe):

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <force:canvasApp developerName="canvasapp"/>
    <!--<iframe src="https://canvasapp.herokuapp.com/" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>-->
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me.

[image]

Below is my connected app settings. key is eventhough your heroku app doesnt have any authentication you still need to enable oAuth settings in connected app

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am facing issue while integrating the canvas app on force.com site using signed request. Are you using the same in the above example?

Comment: @Uday your question says community? canvas app needs session so you need to use an authenticated user to test it not guest user. also on the canvas app profiles give access to profiles for whom you need the canvas app to render. Yes i am using signed request(POST) method